# ASP.NET MVC 2.0 does not install with visual studio 2010 professional?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installation

Hi all I installed vs 2010  and it should have asp.net mvc 2.0 but it didnt install it. I tried installing it manually but it still does not show under the new projects tab..but it shows installed in control panel. I had vs2010 rc1 before and uninstalled it and it had mvc 2.0 but now for some reason i dont have it! ..Can anyone please help  me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>MVC is published standalone. ASP.NET 4.0 is bundled with VStudio 2010, but you'll need to either download MVC 2.0 or install it using the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)</strike>

You're right. Sorry, I had a small brain-fart there. If the projects aren't showing up in the `New->Project` Dialog, that doesn't neccesarily mean MVC isn't installed, It may just be installed *Incorrectly*.

Are the assemblies registered in the GAC, you should check this. Also check your VS2010 configuration to see where it's pointing for it's project templates, and verify the files aren't there.

Check that the AddIn DLL is where it should be:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.2.0.dll`

Comment: MVC 2 is in the box in VS 2010.

Comment: I am going to try and reinstallin vs 2010...for some reason does nt show mvc 2.0

Comment: Updated my answer with a response that isn't completely foolish.